# Meteor run iOS on Xcode 7 doesn't install or run anything

Tags: ios, meteor, xcode7-beta6

I've created a Meteor app. I've added the iOS platform, but when use

```
meteor run ios
```

even though it seems to work fine and the simulator loads, it doesn't install or run any app. What am I doing wrong? Or is it because I'm using Xcode 7 beta?

Answer (score 0):

To run on a actual device, you need a different command;

```
$ meteor run ios-device
```

If you are using any OAuth Account plugins, you also need to have a `--setting settings.json` parameter, and finnaly you also need to have a a `mobile-config.js` file, specifying your bundle id,, splash screens and icons etc...

A full line to compile and run on a device, using a server running on a cloud provide (e.g. amazon.host.com) would look something like this;

```
$ meteor run ios-device --production --mobile-server amazon.host.com --settings settings.json
```